# Failed to install "tango core" app on Lenovo Phab2 plus mobile phone

Tags: android, google-project-tango

I have a Lenovo PHAB2 plus PB2 670N mobile phone, and now I want to run Tango C API on this device. But when I run the cpp_basic_examples on Android Studio, I failed to install "HelloMotionTracking" apk on the Phab2 with error INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY.

As I known it is because of the lack of Tango core, and Tango core can only installed in Google Play Store. But Google Play Store on this mobile phone doesn't work and I can't install  Tango core. I can access the Google site. How do I fix this problem?

Thanks！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tango won't work on the Phab 2 Plus as it doesn't have the required Tango hardware. You'll need to upgrade to the Phab 2 PRO.

Comment: Thinks for your answer. So if I use Phab2 pro, I could run google play store and install tango core successfully, and could run cpp_basic_examples, right?

Comment: Yes, It will.Tango features need Hardware support. meaning that you currently you can ran on Phab2 Pro and Dev kit (Yellowstone)